# Eclipse　画面下部の設定を元に戻したい

Tags: eclipse

Eclipseを利用した開発作業にチャレンジしています。言語はPHPです。

Eclipseでの実行操作時
画面下部に表れていた　ブラウザ出力　や　デバッグ出力　のタブに表れていた内容がかつて大変参考なったのですが、現在これらタグを添付のように誤って消してしまいました。

如何したら　これらタブを元に戻すことができるのでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

レイアウトを初期状態に戻すのであれば、「ウィンドウ」 > 「パースペクティブ」 > 「パースペクティブのリセット」ですね。

Comment: ご見解をありがとうございます。

早速のパースペクティブのリセットという操作を試したところ
デバッグ側の画面下部は、デバッグ出力とブラウザ出力のタブが現れたのですが、
PHP側の画面下部は　元に戻りません。ちらつきはしましたが。

Eclipse右上に虫マークとPHPマークのアイコンがあって、画面が切替えられるようになっています。
（添付の画面に写っていませんが）
どちらとも右下に上記の画面が現れていますが、デバッグ側の画面しか元に戻っていない
ということです。

困りました．．．

Comment: PHPのパースペクティブを開いてから（「ウィンドウ」 > 「パースペクティブ」 > 「パースペクティブを開く」 > 「その他」 > 「PHP」）、もう一度「ウィンドウ」 > 「パースペクティブ」 > 「パースペクティブのリセット」してみて下さい。

Comment: お付き合いを頂きまして誠にありがとうございます。
「ウィンドウ」>「パースペクティブ」ではなく、
「ウィンドウ」>「ビューの表示」>「その他」>「PHPツール」>>>で
"デバッグ出力"と"ブラウザ出力"を選択して、無事表示を元に戻すことができました。

お時間を頂きましてありがとうございました。

Comment: @saya24 そうでしたか。解決したら、回答を承認しておいてください。